# Subsetting sas data set without creating new data file, rather creating a new variable

Tags: sas

I have 3 variables in my data set: `id`, `Time`, and `y1`.

Now I want to create a new variable with the value of `y1` when `Time=1`.

How can I do it?

Comment: Your title and your question don't align, IMO.  Also, please ask one question per post.  You ask about creating a new variable but title refers to subsetting data.  What are you trying to do, and what have you tried?

Comment: Removed your second question; if you want to ask about a second issue, ask a separate question.

Comment: @RobertPenridge I rolled back your change; you lost something significant in that title change, specifically, that the OP is asking how to do it _without creating a new datafile_.  That's significant.

Comment: @Joe Then I think a modification may have been more appropriate rather than a rollback.  Also, if that's the case, are they wanting to do an in-place modification of the dataset (which may be desired for ridiculously large files), or create a new dataset containing the same name.  That's important too because the former won't allow the addition of a new column (which I believe is an important detail to explicitly point out if that's what they are wanting to do).

Answer (score 3):

You always need to *Create* a new dataset, but it doesn't have to have a different name.

```
data have;
  set have;
  if time=1 then y1_time1=y1;
run;
```

SAS will create a second `have`, and then if the data step completes without error it replaces the first `have` with the second one.  This assumes you have the default settings for `replace` (data sets automatically allow replacing, unless you set them not to).

Comment: It may be beneficial to clarify "*You always need to Create a new dataset*" with something like "*when adding a new column*".